# How to make the author and year show when citing a source

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I am trying to cite a source in my file. I want it to come out as "(see Author et al. (Year) for a discussion)". I already have the natbib package in use, and I set my \bibliographystyle to {plainnat}. However, what comes out when I generate the pdf file is:

(see (author?) [1] for a discussion)

with "(author?)" in bold text. How can I show the author/s and the year instead of the reference number?

Answer (score 3):

After loading `natbib`, but still in the preamble, provide the instruction

```
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round}
```

Alternatively, you could load the `natbib` package with the options `authoryear` and `round`:

```
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
```